# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /:\d+$/: Regular expression too large" given by Chrome 95

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

My project runs well in Firefox and <=Chrome 94. When the Chrome updates to 95, it giving an Error
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /:\d+$/: Regular expression too large`.
This is the related code

```js
export const baseURL = (window.location.origin || 'https://www.xxxxx.com')
      .replace(/:\d+$/, '')
      .replace(/\/\/(\S+?)\./, (_a, _p1) => `//${window.station === 'cn' ? 'aaaa' : 'bbbb'}.`);
```

It will give the same Error even if I change the /:\d+$/ => /:233\d/
I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: What is even the goal of this code? Why does it need to be regex?

Answer (score -1):

Do you need to use regex?
I don't know the purpose of this code but you could just use .replace() with a string instead of regex.

Like this:

```js
let text = "https://stackoverflow.com";

console.log(text);

text = text.replace("stackoverflow", "www.stackoverflow");

console.log(text);
```